# Override default current user to Guardian current user with Canary

Tags: authorization, elixir, phoenix-framework, guardian

I am trying to implement Canary into my application, and I have come across a problem. The docs (https://github.com/cpjk/canary#overriding-the-default-user) say that I need to have an Ecto record for the current user in `conn.assigns.current_user`. Since I am using Guardian, my current user is stored in `Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)`. What is the best way to let canary know that this is where I store my current user?

I can't use the `config :canary, current_user: :my_user_key` because it isn't even in `conn.assigns`.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this article](http://learningelixir.joekain.com/using-guardian-and-canary-with-phoenix/), you should create a Plug for that:

```
defmodule MyApp.Plug.CurrentUser do
  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    current_user = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)
    Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :current_user, current_user)
  end
end
```

and put it in a router pipeline:

```
pipeline :require_login do
  plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated, handler: MyApp.GuardianErrorHandler
  plug MyApp.Plug.CurrentUser
end
```

Comment: I ended up doing that, but it took me a while to figure out that I had to put the plug right after the EnsureAuthenticated plug. Thanks!